# How to wrap the shell code like $(ls /all) in the string which to be executed in the docker container by docker exec?

Tags: linux, bash, docker, shell, containers

When I use docker, I want to do some operations in the container for host by `docker exec`, I meet the problem.

I want do something like this but with error:

```
# in host
docker exec test-container bash -c "for i in `ls /folder-in-docker`; do someoperationon($i); done"
```

I simplify the problem reproduced with a command:

```bash
# host environment
docker exec test-container bash -c "for i in `ls /`; do echo $i; done"
>! bash: -c: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `boot'
>! bash: -c: line 2: `boot
```

I want the code "for i in `ls /`; do echo $i; done" executed in the container, but `ls /` is done in the host environment.
In host environment, the result `ls /` is

```bash
bin  boot  cdrom  dev  etc  home  lib  lib32  lib64  libx32  lost+found  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  snap  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

I try other way like `$(ls /)`, but also with error:

```bash
docker exec test bash -c "for i in $(ls /); do echo $i; done"
>! bash: -c: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `boot'
>! bash: -c: line 2: `boot'
```

Comment: Using output of `ls` is a no go.

Comment: @Cyrus : true, but a more stringent problem is that the `ls` command is executed outside docker. So, while this command indeed is not really meaningful, it does not explain to me why you get **this** syntax error. Out of curiosity, I would run the code with `set -x` enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes.

```
docker exec test-container bash -c 'for i in /folder-in-docker/*; do someoperationon($i); done'
```

Best is to let Bash handle it.

```
func() {
   for i in /folder-in-docker/*; do someoperationon($i); done
}
docker exec test-container bash -c "$(declare -f func); func"
```

Note: do not parse ls, do not use backticks, check your scripts with shellcheck.